# Material Design DialogHost doesn't close after First Page Load in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, urhosharp

I've been working with this WPF application that integrates a UrhoSharp Window. When I click somewhere in the Urho window, there's this dialog that pops up as rendered by the main WPF Application.

The issue is that on every application startup or first page load, the dialog pops as it should but doesn't respond to any of the user actions (the dialog has buttons in it) which is supposed to close the dialog eventually. However, if I resize the window or just click the application in the Start Bar, the dialog now responds(happily ever after). This issue doesn't return until I exit the current application page and switch back to the same page. The case is also the same for every application startup.

All the buttons in the dialog executes this command:

```
ICommand cmd = DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand;
Execute(null);
```

And the `CloseDialogCommand` is awaited like this:

```
var dialog = new SomeDialog();
dialog = (SomeDialog)await Controller.dialogHandler(dialog, true);
```

I couldn't figure out what the issue actually is. May be some help would do good.